# Why is multiprocessing.apply_async unpacking a string as arguments?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to do some multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
  pool.apply_async(func,('some string'))
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: func() takes 1 positional arguments but 261 were given

This is very suspicious because the string I was using as the argument had 260 characters.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Replace `('some string')` with `('some string',)`. The former uses a string and the latter a tuple of string.

Comment: Would you write that as an aswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (emphasis mine!),

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1 items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; **a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses)**. Ugly, but effective.

So, the expression `('a')` is actually creating a string of value `'a'`, but the expression `('a',)` is creating a tuple of a single string element `'a'`.

That said, you can refactor your code as

```py
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
  pool.apply_async(func, ('some string',))
```